# Right answer but no Right Question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, answers

When we answer questions in SO, the person who asked the question has the capability to select which answer solved his/her problem or was most helpful.
I wonder if SO could implement a similar methodology for asking the right questions.
I remember the old adage "An answer may not be right but a question is always right"

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Did you put those grammar mistakes back in just to make a point TXI?

Comment: Asking questions when you're drunk is appreciated here. But you should mention it to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @EBGreen: conflicting edits

Comment: I'll take basic programming topics for $200 please Alex...

Comment: @TXI - Aaah...I thought you were just jacking with me.

Comment: I'm interpreting this to mean that the community thinks the question is a valuable question to ask.  For the most part, I'm with @Bill the Lizard on this one -- voting!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think up/down voting serves this purpose.

Comment: +++ I get a huge kick out of upvoting questions that came up with I Googled a topic.

Comment: Taking from EBGreen - what was the question here?

Comment: @Cawas: He was asking if we could have some mechanism similar to accepting an answer that will promote asking good questions.

Comment: oh ok, now I see. It would be like "accepting a question". Good answer, and thanks for the follow up! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what anyone can really say about this.

What exactly is "the right question?" Is this some type of contrived method of awarding someone for **NOT** posting a completely garbage question? Don't we already generally do that by upvoting the question itself?

I don't see the point in this or how it would be useful or beneficial at all.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, I think there are two ways to approach this.  The current way is to have votes on a question mark it's "usefulness" or, as you put it, whether it is the "right question."  This is more or less successful, though people tend to find fun questions more useful than programming questions.

Another way to measure this is the count of how many people have bookmarked a question as their favorite.  Marking a question as a favorite means "This is valuable enough to me that I want to easily find it."  You can easily see how many people have "favorited" a question by looking at the count under the star below the question's vote count.  It may be useful to be able to sort questions by the count of people who have marked them as a favorite, but I'd need to be convinced that this doesn't mirror the vote count before I'd be in favor of it.

Answer (score 0):

> "An answer may not be right but a question is always right"

Doesn't that demonstrate that there's no need to encourage "right" questions?

Answer (score 0):

How would it work, exactly?

As it stands, popular questions (that is, those voted up) are relatively easy to find. Questions with a lot of activity are easy to find. I'm not sure what this would really accomplish, nor even how to implement it in a way that doesn't make finding less-popular questions harder/impossible.